# Only the first item is missed from ArrayList while reading from csv file

Tags: java, arraylist

I have tried to read String from a CSV file and store it to the `ArrayList`. But when searching the index of the first item in the `ArrayList`, it returns -1. Or when I tried to check whether a given string and the first element of the `ArrayList` is equal, equals method does not work.

Here is my code:

```
class Database<T>{
    ArrayList<String> firstLine = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<ArrayList<T>> veri = new ArrayList<ArrayList<T>>();
    public Database(){}
    public Database(String dosyaIsmi) {
        Scanner in = null;
        Scanner lineT = null;
        try {
            in = new Scanner(new File(dosyaIsmi));
            lineT = new Scanner(in.nextLine()).useDelimiter(";");
            while(lineT.hasNext()) {
                String StringObj = lineT.next();
                firstLine.add(StringObj);
            }
            while(in.hasNextLine()) {
                ArrayList<T> temp = new ArrayList<>();
                lineT = new Scanner(in.nextLine()).useDelimiter(";");
                if(lineT.hasNextInt()) {
                    while(lineT.hasNext()) {
                        if(lineT.hasNextInt()) {
                            Integer intObj = lineT.nextInt();
                            temp.add((T) intObj);
                        }
                        else
                            throw new FileNotFoundException();
                    }
                }
                else if(lineT.hasNextDouble()) {
                    while(lineT.hasNext()) {
                        if(lineT.hasNextDouble()) {
                            Double doubleObj = lineT.nextDouble();
                            temp.add((T) doubleObj);
                        }
                        else
                            throw new FileNotFoundException();
                    }
                }
                else {
                    while(lineT.hasNext()) {
                        if(lineT.hasNextInt())
                            throw new FileNotFoundException();
                        else if(lineT.hasNextDouble())
                            throw new FileNotFoundException();
                        else {
                            String stringObj = lineT.next();
                            temp.add((T) stringObj);
                        }
                    }
                }
                veri.add(temp);
            }
            in.close();
            lineT.close();
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            veri = new ArrayList<ArrayList<T>>();
            System.out.println("Dosya ile ilgili bir hata olustu.");
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Dosya ile ilgili bir hata olustu.");
        }
    }

    public Database join(Database second, String column_name){
        Database newObj = new Database();
        for(int i=0; i<firstLine.size(); i++)
        System.out.print(firstLine.get(i));
        int firstIndex = firstLine.indexOf(column_name);
        int secondIndex = second.firstLine.indexOf(column_name);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the column_name variable? it returns -1 because it cannot find the value of the column_name variable: 

     * @return  the index of the first occurrence of the specified substring,
     *          or {@code -1} if there is no such occurrence.

Comment: There are 3 columns in my csv file. First is : PLAYER, second: POSITION, third: TEAM. So firstLine arraylist is --> ["PLAYER", "POSITION", "TEAM"]
If I call join method like that --> join(secObj, "POSITION"), firstindex variable becomes 1.But if I call join method like that --> join(secObj, "PLAYER"), firstindex variable becomes -1 instead of 0.